# How do I create a URL that points to a specific BMC Trackit ticket?

Tags: issue-tracking

Our IT group uses BMC Track-It!  I'd like to create a URL that takes me directly to a specific ticket (#13239).
Here's the URL to the Track-It system:

```
https://TrackIt/tms/SelfService/Application/Main
```

The URL that Track-It! emails to "...view the request here" just takes me a generic TrackIt page -- not the specific item:

```
https://TrackIt/tms/SelfService
```

I used Firefox dev tools to watch what the server does when I click on "my tickets" then on the specific ticket.  It sends these POST URLS, but they just return JSON data:

```
https://TrackIt/tms/SelfService/HelpDesk/GetIncidents?_dc=1618242834846
https://TrackIt/tms/SelfService/HelpDesk/GetIncident/13239
```

Is it possible to format a URL that will take me directly to my ticket?

[edit]

I want the format of a URL that I can put into an email or a JIRA ticket.  Clicking in that link should take the user to our existing TrackIt system and display a known Ticket / Issue / Item / Case.

Comment: these URLs are invalid. May be they use this more than one step for security , authentication , some cookie during steps .   Anyway  if you  have access to json data you can automate the various steps, in the programming language you choose.  Python or Ruby can do it .

Comment: @MarioAbbruscato: <quote>These URLs are invalid</quote> Except for the obfuscated server name, these are URLs that work in *our* system.  I edited the original post to provide a usage model for my context.